# Extract directories from string

Tags: java, regex, string

I need to extract the directory for a string, examples are as follows:

```
222.77.201.211 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:23 +0800] "GET /mapreduce-nextgen/hadoop-internals-mapreduce-reference/ HTTP/1.1" 200 28664 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
220.181.89.164 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:25 +0800] "GET /mapreduce/hadoop-capacity-scheduler HTTP/1.1" 301 390 "-" "Sogou web spider/4.0(+http://www.sogou.com/docs/help/webmasters.htm#07)"
175.44.54.185 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:25 +0800] "GET /mapreduce-nextgen/apache-hadoop-2-0-3-published HTTP/1.1" 301 439 "http://dongxicheng.org/mapreduce-nextgen/apache-hadoop-2-0-3-published/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
175.44.54.185 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:25 +0800] "GET /search-engine/scribe-intro/ HTTP/1.1" 200 21578 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
112.111.174.38 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:30 +0800] "GET /structure/segment-tree HTTP/1.1" 301 414 "http://dongxicheng.org/structure/segment-tree/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
112.111.174.38 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:30 +0800] "GET /structure/segment-tree HTTP/1.1" 301 414 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
222.77.201.211 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:31 +0800] "GET /mapreduce-nextgen/apache-hadoop-2-0-3-published/ HTTP/1.1" 200 23438 "http://dongxicheng.org/mapreduce-nextgen/apache-hadoop-2-0-3-published/" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)"
```

The expected output would be:

- `/mapreduce-nextgen/hadoop-internals-mapreduce-reference/`
- `/mapreduce/hadoop-capacity-scheduler`
- `/mapreduce-nextgen/apache-hadoop-2-0-3-published`
- etc...

I think a regular expression might be needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the directory you are looking for always between 'GET' and 'HTTP'?

Comment: Add some additional examples of your strings

Comment: Yep, it will always be in that format. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the answers above would have worked and are probably better but I did it using `.indexOf()`.
The first line reading in the text isn't exactly how I did it as Hadoop handled that but for brevity here it is.

```
Text value = "112.111.186.210 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:22 +0800] \"GET /structure/segment-tree HTTP/1.1\" 301 414 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)\"","GET ", " HTTP"


     int idx = value.toString().indexOf("GET");
     int idy = value.toString().indexOf("HTTP/1");
     ip.set(value.toString().substring(idx, idy).trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's always between `GET` and `HTTP`, the easiest Regex would be this one:

```
GET (.*?) HTTP
```

Prove here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aH9yS4/1)

In Java, the code should be like the following one:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("GET (.*?) HTTP");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
```

Edit: Don't forget to put `\` before every `"` in the String, otherwise it would be interpreted as the end of your String.

```
String str = "222.77.201.211 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:23 +0800] \"GET /mapreduce-nextgen/hadoop-internals-mapreduce-reference/ HTTP/1.1\" 200 28664 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)\"";
```

Your output withing the String above will be `/mapreduce-nextgen/hadoop-internals-mapreduce-reference/`.

Comment: How can I escape every \ in the String? I am reading each line in from a file. Thanks

Comment: This way: `String parts[] = str.split("\\");`

Answer (score 2):

```
String toInspect = "112.111.186.210 - - [20/Sep/2013:00:10:22 +0800] \"GET /structure/segment-tree HTTP/1.1\" 301 414 \"-\" \"Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1;)\"";
String directory = StringUtils.substringBetween(toInspect ,"GET ", " HTTP");
```

Comment: Note that this is part of Apache Commons (AFAIK), so you'll need that library.